# how can i change a list view item text when clicking on it while using a long list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

how can  i change a list view item text when clicking on it while using  a long  list in flutter. Please help me to solve this problem....

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
runApp(MaterialApp(
title:'exploring ui widgets',
home:Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(title: Text('long list'),),
body: getListView(),
),
));
}
List<String>getListElements(){
  var items=List<String>.generate(1000, (counter) => 'item $counter');
  return items;
}

Widget getListView(){
  var listItems=getListElements();
  var listView=ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          title: Text(listItems[index]),

          onTap: () {

          },
        );

      });
    return listView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would break your problem down as it will be easier to manage.

Create a separate Widget and build them in the item builder. Then in that widget you can have a way of toggling to update the string that backs the title.

After this is working you might want to read about [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) and [adding interactivity](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) to your app.

Full example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'exploring ui widgets',
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('long list'),
      ),
      body: MyListView(),
    ),
  ));
}

List<String> getListElements() {
  var items = List<String>.generate(1000, (counter) => 'item $counter');
  return items;
}

class MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var listItems = getListElements();
    var listView = ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listItems.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyListItem(listItems[index]),
    );
    return listView;
  }
}

class MyListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyListItem(this.title); //pass the title in

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyListItemState();
}

class _MyListItemState extends State<MyListItem> {
  bool _toggle = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final text = _toggle ? widget.title : 'other'; //when true show title, when false show 'other'

    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
      title: Text(text),
      onTap: () {
        //setState will trigger a re build of this widget and ONLY this widget not the whole list
        setState(() {
          _toggle = !_toggle; //invert the toggle to swap the text
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if its helped :)